# HTTP.sys vs Kestrel: Why choose one over the other? Pros Cons?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

What is the reason for two separate but similar servers?
What are the differences?
Can I run both in docker?
Do both support same things, like all authentication types?

Comment: pretty sure weblistener is windows only, kestrel is cross platform

Comment: Read the docs! https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html :)

Comment: If Kestrel is cross platform then whey can't them make it support all options that work for windows on WebListener. Why do I have to hardcode in my app Main what type of server am I going to use?!

Comment: The docs are lacking on this question, @DavidG. The section [Choosing a server](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html#choosing-a-server), which should be the canonical answer to this question, doesn't even mention WebListener, much less offer guidance about when to choose it.

Comment: @EdwardBrey Then feel free to [update the docs](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnet/fundamentals/servers.rst) if you feel they need more info

Comment: @DavidG That would be a great suggestion if I knew the answer. I fell back to the next best option, which is to [log an issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/1959) to alert someone who does.

Comment: I now know that Kestler does not support windows auth but why would someone create two projects instead of just making one server in modular architecture and support some modules on windows and some on linux. And then if you add issues like that one when simple change ÜseKestler tu UseWeblistener will instantly make website crashing on iis express... Then you have to work hard to make your project run on all types of servers which is like... contradictory to making things abstract and independednt - what it was all about...

Answer (score 47):

**Kestrel vs HTTP.sys** - I've highlighted the fundamental differences below.

*(The words are Microsoft's and I've only edited it for brevity and clarity. See the sources linked at the bottom).*

---

## **Update:**

Kestrel previously always required the use of a reverse proxy with edge deployments (exposed to traffic from the Internet) for security reasons. With Kestrel in ASP.Net Core 2.x this is no longer the case. Take a look at the documentation for more information. [Kestrel Web Server Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#when-to-use-kestrel-with-a-reverse-proxy)

[image: Kestrel 1.x vs 2.x]

[Weblistener was renamed HTTP.sys in ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/2648)

#### Sources:

1. **Docs.Microsoft.com** [Web server implementations in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/)
2. **Docs.Microsoft.com** [HTTP.sys web server implementation in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/HTTP.sys#when-to-use-HTTP.sys)

**HTTP.sys** is ***windows-only*** HTTP / Web Server for ASP.NET Core that allows you to expose the server ***directly to the Internet*** without needing to use IIS. HTTP.sys is built on top of Http.Sys ( the same mature technology that also powers IIS' HTTP Listener) as is as such ***very feature rich*** and ***provides protection against various attacks***.

**Kestrel** on the other hand, is a ***cross-platform*** web server for ASP.NET Core that is designed to be ***run behind a proxy*** (for example IIS or Nginx) and ***should not be deployed directly facing the Internet***. Kestrel is relatively new and ***does not have a full complement of defenses against attacks***. It's also ***not as feature rich*** as HTTP.sys and comes with timeout limits, size limits and concurrent user limits.

---

In essence, the choice comes down to your web application's Deployment scenario.

### HTTP.sys Use Cases :

[image]

### Kestrel Use Cases :

[image]

Comment: It's worth mentioning that for proper protection you'll want a Web Application Firewall anyway (e.g. using Azure Application Gateway).

Comment: FWIW `concurrent connection limits` means with kestrel you can load the server until it fractures, whereas with IIS will queue requests, run them slower, and only under extreme load return service unavailable errors whereas kestrel will eventually stop responding appropriately.

Comment: Update: `Http.sys` is the new name of `WebListener`: 
[HTTP.sys web server implementation in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Answer (score 4):

Following  comparison will help you to choose which one is better

[image]

Comment: Can you attribute the source of the table?

Comment: A similar source: http://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html

Answer (score 3):

The ASP.NET 5 documentation (*created by Microsoft on August 25, 2015*) found here lists the chart found in the other answer  (see page 107 of the bottom right book pages, but page 111 of the PDF): https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/aspnet/theming/aspnet.pdf

**Kestrel** in general has better performance, if you used for one of the following below:

- Great option if used in conjunction with a reverse proxy for apps exposed to Internet
- Internal apps connecting with other internal apps on a private virtual network (not exposed to Internet)

**WebListener** is more secure, slower, and has more features.  It is used in these cases:

- Expose app to the Internet but can't use IIS
  Require higher security and exposing server directly to Internet.
- Additional features: List item, Windows Authentication, Port sharing, HTTPS with SNI, HTTP/2 over TLS (Windows 10), Direct file transmission, Response caching